# How to determine if a key is pressed in python using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Is there a really simple way of knowing if the key `SPACE` is currently `DOWN`. I'm making a basic snake game and I don't know to use `pygame` and I can't find it anywhere.

I imagine it like something along these lines:

```
if K_SPACE = DOWN:
     turtle.turn(90)
```

thank you for any help

Comment: Have you done any research, beyond just imagining?

Comment: Your imagined command would not work: it leads to a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I imagine you need to work more on your Python skills first.

Comment: What is `turtle` doing there? I mean why are you using module turtle with pygame?

Answer (score 0):

In your game loop:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            turtle.turn(90)
```